# While loop based on component state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, while-loop, jsx

I am working on a calculator app with React. I want to set the innerText of the AC button C while there is a value in the component's state. For example,

```
while (this.state.number) {
    document.getElementById("AC").innerText = "C";
}
```

I know this is invalid JSX. So I want to know what is another way to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't suggest you using DOM manipulation to achieve the task. And while loop is synchronous, once true it will always run and prevent other events from firing to update the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rendering `AC` Button as react element you can do something like this.

```
...

<button>
{
 this.state.number ? "C" : "AC"
}
</button>
...
```